# Script language for cross platform development for all relevant platforms

Tags: scripting, cross-platform

I have a feeling stackoverflow might not be the right place to ask this question, but I'm not sure if http://programmers.stackexchange.com would be a better place...

Anyways, I'm looking for a simple way to write applications for all relevant platforms (Win, Mac OSX, Linux, Android, iOS). 
In a language like JavaScript, Lua, Python, Ruby....

I really like Lua, nice syntax, small, but it's really hard to get a base working in C/C++.
JavaScript is also really nice syntax wise, especially with Ecma6 classes, but nodejs is way too big...
Python is also not really small. On Windows, Linux and Mac OSX it's probably really nice. But mobile apps would need the whole interpreter inside of them.

Has anyone of you experience with this? Or is there simply no reasonable way around C/C++/Java?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plan for cross-platform app then JavaScript is best language as per my experience. I have created a lots of App using JavaScript in all platform. It is really very nice performance and syntax.

Comment: How big are the apps? Which engine do you use? Do you have to write the base in a lower level language?

Comment: Nearly 10-15 Screens in apps. I am using cordova for cross platform apps, for UI contents there are so many frameworks available like jQuery Mobile, Ratchet.js, Famo.

Comment: I didn't mean the screen size, I meant the file size. :P And does cordova also work on Windows, Linux and Mac OSX?

Comment: My App size is around 5 MB and yeah I created app in Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

Comment: 5MB that's really impressive! And can you also compile it to run on a desktop computer? Or is it for mobile apps only?

Comment: I created only Mobile Apps